# Align Bootstrap Button to right hand side of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm brand new to all of this. This is my first ever actual project with HTML/CSS, so please keep that in mind. Constructive criticism is always welcome, as it will only help me become better.

Now that that's out of the way, my issue:

So, I'm using Bootstrap because it's easy to use and from my experience so far is somewhat user friendly. I can't for the lift of me however figure out how to move my dropdown button to the right-hand side of my navbar.

Here's the code for my navbar (again, sorry if it's trash. New to this):

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">AVC Gaming</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Forums <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Ban Appeal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="button"><a href="">Donate</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">UK 111 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Arma 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Arma 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want, there is a live version here: http://www.avc-gaming.us/avc

I've tried adding "pull-right" to the UK 111 dropdown `<ul>` but that didn't do anything. When I added "pull-right" to the Donate button, all it did was swap places with the UK 111 dropdown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which one of the dropdowns? All of them? And also, can you add some CSS and minimal code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Wow, I'm really sorry. The last one, the one that says "UK 111" in it.

Comment: IF i understand correctly, you can add `style="float:right"` to your dropdown? However, i do not know how the other containers are styled so not sure if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pull-right works like it should. But because the width of `ul.nav navbar-nav` is just taking up the space of it's content it's not working like you want. If you'll put a width of for example 90% on `ul.nav navbar-nav` you will see it aligns right.

Comment: I moved the navbar-brand into the <ul>, added an ID to the <ul>, then in CSS set the width to 100%, and it's aligned all the way to the right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move All of them to the right of the page put `Float:right` in line `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` like so:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">AVC Gaming</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Forums <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Ban Appeal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="button"><a href="">Donate</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">UK 111 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Arma 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Arma 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

OR

If you want to move just the last one then set `Width:96%` on line `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` and `float:Right` on your last dropdownlist `<li class="dropdown">`

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">AVC Gaming</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="Width:96%">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Forums <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Ban Appeal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="button"><a href="">Donate</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown" style="Float:right">
                <a href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">UK 111 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Arma 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Arma 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move `<li>` of UK 111 to separate `<ul>` and add 'pull-right' class to it along with other classes that you are using for styling your list.

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="http://forums.avc-gaming.us" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Forums <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Ban Appeal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="button"><a href="">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="http://www.uk111.uk" role="button" aria-expanded="false">UK 111 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.uk111.uk/forum">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.uk111.uk/a2servers">Arma 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.uk111.uk/a3servers">Arma 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add bootstrap's own class `pull-right`. I have a example here!

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid pull-right">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 provides this functionality. Please refer to the Docs for a complete [example](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and specifically for right aligned links: [Component Alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment)

About Pull-right and Navbars

> Align nav links, forms, buttons, or text, using the .navbar-left or
>   .navbar-right utility classes. Both classes will add a CSS float in
>   the specified direction. For example, to align nav links, put them in
>   a separate `<ul>` with the respective utility class applied.
>
> These classes are mixin-ed versions of .pull-left and .pull-right, but
>   they're scoped to media queries for easier handling of navbar
>   components across device sizes.

Component Alignment

> Right aligning multiple components Navbars currently have a limitation
>   with multiple .navbar-right classes. To properly space content, we use
>   negative margin on the last .navbar-right element. When there are
>   multiple elements using that class, these margins don't work as
>   intended.

See complete working example Snippet at FullPage.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">AVC Gaming</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Forums <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Ban Appeal</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Registration</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="button"><a href="#">Donate</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">UK 111 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Arma 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Arma 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```